# Hide/Show Form Fields with CSS and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Like stated in this [example](http://pixelentity.com/freebies/hide-form-fields-with-css-and-jquery/), I can show or hide some form elements that are in a specific group, based on the selected item in a combo box.

What I would like to do, is to maintain the same behavior but using links. For example, the first group is:

[image: Login Page]

If I click on **Join us**, I would like to switch (to show) to the second group (and hide the first), like this:

[image]

.. cyclically.

A basic HTML:

```
<div id="registrate" class="group1">
<form action="#" method="post" class="regform">
    <h1><span class="log-in">Log in</span> or <span class="sign-up">sign up</span></h1>

    <p class="float group1_opts">
       <input type="text" name="nickname" id="nickname" placeholder="Username or Email..">
    </p>

    <p class="float group2_opts">
       <input type="text" name="nickname" id="nickname" placeholder="Email..">
    </p>
    <p class="float group2_opts">
       <input type="text" name="nickname" id="nickname" placeholder="Confirm Email..">
    </p>

    <p class="float">
       <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password.." required><br/>
    </p>

    <p class="float group2_opts">
       <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Confirm Password.." required><br/>
    </p>

    <p>
        <div class="remember">
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="None" id="remember">
            <label for="remember"></label>
        </div>
        <label for="remember" class="remembermelabel">Remember Me</label>
    </p> 

    <p class="submit">
        <div class="button">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
        </div>
    </p>
    <h1></h1>
    <p class="change_link group1_opts"> Not a member yet?&nbsp;
        <a href="" class="to_register">Join us</a>
    </p>
    <p class="change_link group2_opts"> Are you just a member?&nbsp;
        <a href="" class="to_login">Login</a>
    </p>
</form>
```

A basic CSS:

```
.group1_opts, .group2_opts {
   display: none;
}

.group1 .group1_opts, .group2 .group2_opts {
   display: block;
}
```

There is a way to obtain this using links instead of combobox, like in the other example?
Thank you

Comment: What about using `.toggle()` on the anchor element?

Comment: I think you forgot to post the jquery you have tried

Comment: @Terry as of jQuery 1.9, `.toggle()` has been deprecated so I'd stay clear of it.

Comment: Working Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hCmr6/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bind to the click events, and show and hide the relevant fields:

```
$('.to_register').click(function() {
  $('.group1_opts').hide();
  $('.group2_opts').show();
});
$('.to_login').click(function() {
  $('.group1_opts').show();
  $('.group2_opts').hide();
});
```

Note that you won't need your CSS to do this - jQuery will take care of hiding/showing the elements for you.

Comment: I would also set the "Email", "Confirm Email" and "Confirm Password" text boxes to "disabled" (using jQuery) when your user "logs in" - this will prevent the items being sent during the POST. Your script can then do a check on whether one of your "disabled" fields was submitted and if it doesn't appear in the POST array (doesn't matter if it was empty or not) then you know if the person is registering or logging in...? You could (in theory) use the same form for login and registration? OR, take all the info, compare it to database, if the username.email and password match, log them in?

Answer (score 2):

@BigChris raises an excellent point, and it's worthy of an answer.

How do you plan to tell if someone submitted a "Registration" or a "Login"?  Simply watching for the right input field(s) won't work, because it's possible someone *starts* to fill in the registration form, but then switches to the login form.

Right now, you have only one form, with one submit button.

For clarity, and to provide a clear separation, not only in your markup but in your form processing on the server, I would **strongly** recommend that you change the markup to be two entirely separate forms.  If you aren't willing / able to do that, then at least create two buttons.

Here's the revised HTML based on the two form concept:

```
<div id="registrate" class="group1">
<h1><span class="log-in">Log in</span> or <span class="sign-up">sign up</span></h1>
<!-- The first form contains only registration info, and a submit named register -->
<form action="#" method="post" class="to_register">
    <p class="float">
       <input type="text" name="nickname" id="nickname" placeholder="Email..">
    </p>
    <p class="float">
       <input type="text" name="nickname" id="nickname" placeholder="Confirm Email..">
    </p>

    <p class="float">
       <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password.." required><br/>
    </p>
    <p class="float">
       <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Confirm Password.." required><br/>
    </p>
    <p class="submit">
        <div class="button">
            <input type="submit" name="register" value="Login">
        </div>
    </p>
</form>
<!-- The second form is purely login, and has a submit named login -->
<form action="#" method="post" class="to_login">
    <p class="float">
       <input type="text" name="nickname" id="nickname" placeholder="Username or Email..">
    </p>
    <p class="float">
       <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password.." required><br/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <div class="remember">
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="None" id="remember">
            <label for="remember"></label>
        </div>
        <label for="remember" class="remembermelabel">Remember Me</label>
    </p> 
    <p class="submit">
        <div class="button">
            <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
        </div>
    </p>
</form> 
    <h1></h1>
    <p class="change_link group1_opts"> Not a member yet?&nbsp;
        <a href="" class="to_register">Join us</a>
    </p>
    <p class="change_link group2_opts"> Are you just a member?&nbsp;
        <a href="" class="to_login">Login</a>
    </p>
 </div>
```

Note that I've changed the classes of the forms, and removed the classes on the p tags.  The classes of the forms match the class of the links, so that the jQuery is simpler.

Then, your jQuery becomes:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('a.to_register, a.to_login').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var cname = $(this).attr('class');
        $('form.' + cname).show();
        $('form').not('.' + cname).hide();
    });
});
```

Now, depending on your server-side language, you can watch for either `$_POST['register']` or `$_POST['login']` (the names of the submit buttons), to detect which they clicked, and what they intended.

Comment: We had the same thoughts lol, btw don't forget your preventDefault();

Answer (score 1):

using jQuery you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.to_register, .to_login').click(function() {
         $('.group1_opts').toggle();
         $('.group2_opts').toggle();
    });

});
```

edit: this works as long as the right stuff is hidden and shown at first

Comment: Why not combine this for simplicity, since both functions do exactly the same thing? `$('.to_login, .to_register').click(...)`

Comment: agree, nice observation

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript (sorry but I'm not using jQuery):

For that you need to use the `onclick` action from JavaScript and like your address "join us" to "#" to make it stay on the same page. Actually you can use `onclick` with pretty much anything so feel free to use a `<p>`, `<img>` or what ever.
To make disappear / appear your input, just use:

```
function hide(id)
{
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    element.style ="display: none;";
}
```

Also you can change the value of your `<p>` from "Join us" to "Login" and also change the action you want to call with `onclick` (switch between hide/show(id) and `element.setAttribute("onclick", full_function);`).

Answer (score 1):

I would honestly make two seperate forms. The code is very simple, and you can set two different actions in your forms. -- DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/hCmr6/

jQuery:

```
$('.to_register, .to_login').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.loginform, .regform').slideToggle(400);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="registrate" class="group1">
    <h1><span class="log-in">Log in</span> or <span class="sign-up">sign up</span></h1>
    <form action="#" method="post" class="loginform">
        <p class="float group1_opts">
            <input type="text" name="nickname" id="nickname" placeholder="Username or Email.." />
        </p>
        <p class="float">
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password.." required />
            <br/>
        </p>
        <p class="float group2_opts"></p>
        <p>
            <div class="remember">
                <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="None" id="remember" />
                <label for="remember"></label>
            </div>
            <label for="remember" class="remembermelabel">Remember Me</label>
        </p>
        <p class="submit">
            <div class="button">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
            </div>
        </p>
         <h1></h1>

        <p class="change_link group1_opts">Not a member yet?&nbsp; <a href="" class="to_register">Join us</a>

        </p>
    </form>


    <form action="#" method="post" class="regform">
        <p class="float group1_opts">
            <input type="text" name="nickname" id="nickname" placeholder="Username or Email.." />
        </p>
        <p class="float group2_opts">
            <input type="text" name="nickname" id="nickname" placeholder="Email.." />
        </p>
        <p class="float group2_opts">
            <input type="text" name="nickname" id="nickname" placeholder="Confirm Email.." />
        </p>
        <p class="float">
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password.." required />
            <br/>
        </p>
        <p class="float group2_opts">
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Confirm Password.." required />
            <br/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <div class="remember">
                <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="None" id="remember" />
                <label for="remember"></label>
            </div>
            <label for="remember" class="remembermelabel">Remember Me</label>
        </p>
        <p class="submit">
            <div class="button">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
            </div>
        </p>
        <p class="change_link group2_opts">Are you just a member?&nbsp; <a href="" class="to_login">Login</a>

        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions!